# UITableView Background Color Different From UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I am setting the tableView background color the same as the tableViewCell background color, but the colors look different. The colors look the same when set to a custom color but when there is no custom color set they are different. isColorSet is 0 on start so both should be set to `UIColor(red: 74/255, green: 187/255, blue: 224/255, alpha: 1.0)`. How can I get the colors to look the same?

Setting tableView background color:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //Set background color
    if userDefaults.integer(forKey: "isColorSet") == 0 {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 74/255, green: 187/255, blue: 224/255, alpha: 1.0)
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 74/255, green: 187/255, blue: 224/255, alpha: 1.0)

    } else if userDefaults.integer(forKey: "isColorSet") == 1 {
        let red = CGFloat(userDefaults.float(forKey: "red"))
        let green = CGFloat(userDefaults.float(forKey: "green"))
        let blue = CGFloat(userDefaults.float(forKey: "blue"))
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: red/255, green: green/255, blue: blue/255, alpha: 1.0)
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: red/255, green: green/255, blue: blue/255, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Setting tableViewCell background color:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ideaCell") as! IdeaTableViewCell

    cell.ideaTitleLabel.text = ideas[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].title
    cell.ideaDescLabel.text = ideas[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].desc

    //Set date
    let date = userDefaults.object(forKey: "date.\(indexPath.section).\(indexPath.row)") as! Date
    let month = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: date)
    let day = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: date)
    let year = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: date)
    if userDefaults.string(forKey: "dateStyle") == "MDY" {
        cell.ideaDateLabel.text = "\(month)/\(day)/\(year)"
    } else if userDefaults.string(forKey: "dateStyle") == "DMY" {
        cell.ideaDateLabel.text = "\(day)/\(month)/\(year)"
    } else if userDefaults.string(forKey: "dateStyle") == "YMD" {
        cell.ideaDateLabel.text = "\(year)/\(month)/\(day)"
    }

    //Set color
    if userDefaults.integer(forKey: "isColorSet") == 0 {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 74/255, green: 187/225, blue: 224/225, alpha: 1.0)
    } else if userDefaults.integer(forKey: "isColorSet") == 1 {
        let red = CGFloat(userDefaults.float(forKey: "red"))
        let green = CGFloat(userDefaults.float(forKey: "green"))
        let blue = CGFloat(userDefaults.float(forKey: "blue"))
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: red/255, green: green/255, blue: blue/255, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    return cell
```

Setting rgb colors for UserDefaults:

```
func HSBColorColorPickerTouched(sender: HSBColorPicker, color: UIColor, point: CGPoint, state: UIGestureRecognizer.State) {
    setButton.backgroundColor = color
    red = color.rgb()?.red
    green = color.rgb()?.green
    blue = color.rgb()?.blue
    redLabel.text = "Red: \(red!)"
    redSlider.value = Float(red)
    greenLabel.text = "Green: \(green!)"
    greenSlider.value = Float(green)
    blueLabel.text = "Blue: \(blue!)"
    blueSlider.value = Float(blue)
}

@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    red = redSlider.value
    green = greenSlider.value
    blue = blueSlider.value
    if red != nil {
        redLabel.text = "Red: \(red!)"
    }
    if green != nil {
        greenLabel.text = "Green: \(green!)"
    }
    if blue != nil {
        blueLabel.text = "Blue: \(blue!)"
    }
    setButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red/255), green: CGFloat(green/255), blue: CGFloat(blue/255), alpha: 1.0)
}

@IBAction func setColor(_ sender: Any) {
    userDefaults.removeObject(forKey: "red")
    userDefaults.removeObject(forKey: "green")
    userDefaults.removeObject(forKey: "blue")
    userDefaults.set(red, forKey: "red")
    userDefaults.set(green, forKey: "green")
    userDefaults.set(blue, forKey: "blue")
    if userDefaults.float(forKey: "isColorSet") == 0 {
        userDefaults.set(1, forKey: "isColorSet")
    }
    _ = navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

[Screenshot with isColorSet = 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szQfa.png)

[Screenshot with isColorSet = 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdL0T.png)

[Screenshot of Color Picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4EwC.png)

Comment: What color are they when there is no custom color? Include a screenshot if you can.

Comment: @toddg I have added a link to the screenshot because I do not have enough reputation to embed a picture yet.

Comment: ok, got it. Is the problem that you're getting two shades of blue or that the cell is white when it should be blue?

Comment: The problem is that I am getting two shades of blue. I will update the question with a screenshot of when isColorSet is 1.

Comment: It appears that there may be an issue serializing/deserializing to `userDefaults`. Can you post the code that sets these values there? It might help to insert some print statements into that code to see what rgb values you're setting when `isColorSet = 0`

Comment: @toddg I have added the code along with a screenshot of the color picker. Also, the problem is not when the background is set from the saved values in UserDefaults, only when there is not a value saved.

Comment: One step at a time. Assuming you can get the proper color **without** UserDefaults, maybe we can narrow it down to something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is a simple typo in the following line:

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 74/255, green: 187/225, blue: 224/225, alpha: 1.0)
```

Your denominator should be 255 for the green and blue values.

Comment: Oh wow sorry I didn't catch that before asking why this happened. Thanks

Comment: It happens to us all :-)